# Reading hidden field value from webview Android

Tags: android, webview, hidden-field

I am creating an application which has user registration page. This page is loaded from the url in my webview which has submit button. After submitting form it gives the me one hidden field in the next url with userid. My problem is I want read that hidden field value from that url in to my android application.

I have tried using the following function for getting the loading page Event.

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsById('userId').innerHTML+'</head>');");
    }
```

Then my showHtml Method is like this

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface  
 {  
     @SuppressWarnings("unused")  
     public void showHTML(String html)  
     {  
        System.out.println("HTML "+html);


     }  
 }
```

Still I'm not able to get the data of the HTML page loaded after registering the user.
Can any body please guide me what am I doing wrong here? or is this not the way should I get the data of hidden field.

Comment: If the pages HTML is valid, you could try using a SAX Parser or something to parse the HTML. Then you could isolate your hidden field and get it's value. Also, if the service which returns the hidden field is your's, you could make it return an XML-File (to easily parse it) or you could use something like Sockets to do your registration.

Comment: My problem is that i am not able to read html data or Stream because of I don't have control on the loded url in my webview

Answer (score 0):

You could use the '[getProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getProgress%28%29)'-method to check if the site has loaded. After it did, you could use the '[getURL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl%28%29)' e.g. the '[getOriginalURL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getOriginalUrl%28%29)' method to get the URL on which you can then set the Parser to read the value from your hidden field.

If this works with the Service (maybe it's a One-Time-URL, which can't be opened twice).

Anyways, what Service are you trying to code for (if it's not yours)?